# Completeness of posets

Tags: logic, order-theory

I think this is rather a simple question in order theory, but if someone could explain it step by step that would be really useful. If we have an arbitrary set, then let's denote the set of all finite subsets $F$, and the set of all cofinite subsets $C$.

I want to check whether $F,C$ are complete or chain complete, when they are ordered by inclusion.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What would it mean for these to be complete and/or chain complete?

Comment: For $F$, say to be complete, we would need that for all $A \subseteq F$, $A$ has a least upper bound. For $F$ to be chain-complete each chain would need to have a l.u.b.

Comment: You can view these lattices as embedded in the full powerset lattice, where you know what the l.u.b. actually is.  Pick some interesting chains and see if their l.u.b. is actually in the smaller lattice you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set--say $X$--is itself finite, then $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal C$ are simply the power set, which is trivially complete and chain-complete. Now, suppose $X$ is infinite.

Now, assuming that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset, can you think of a chain of finite sets that has no upper bound *in the set* $\mathcal F$? (We can't pull this off without some Choice principle, and I think this is the weakest one that will do the trick.)

Observe that $\bigl\{\{x\}:x\in X\bigr\}$ is a subset of $\mathcal F$. Does it have an upper bound in $\mathcal F$?

Similar (and closely related) counterexamples will show that $\mathcal C$ is neither complete, nor (with sufficient Choice) chain-complete.

---

**Added**: In the case that (chain-)completeness refers only to upper bounds and not lower bounds, then in fact $\mathcal C$ *will* be (chain-)complete. After all, $X\in\mathcal C,$ and for all $A\in\mathcal C$ we have $A\subseteq X.$ This shows that each collection of elements of $\mathcal C$ has an upper bound. Moreover, since for each $A\in\mathcal C$ there are only finitely-many $B\in\mathcal C$ such that $A\subseteq B,$ then there is readily a *least* upper bound for all such collections.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully. Let $X = \mathbb{N}$, for example, let $X_n = \{1,...,n\}$, then $\{X_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a chain consisting of elements of $F$. However, the l.u.b of this chain does not exist in $F$. Do you mean something along these lines...?

Comment: That is precisely what I mean, yes. More generally, if there is a countably infinite subset $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq X,$ then put $X_n=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ for each $n,$ and we come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much.

Comment: @Carl: Excellent point! I was thinking in terms of complete lattices. I will amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user127418: Please see my amended answer. Apologies if the first answer was misleading.